# How to make salesforce tabs look normal even on adding external style sheets to visual force pages

Tags: visualforce, css, stylesheets

Hi i was adding style sheet to my visual force page, it is working fibe but it is affecting  default salesforce tabs look un-user-friendly.

without adding style sheet it is looking like

```
<apex:page standardController="case" extensions="UnclaimedTicket" sidebar="false" tabStyle="case"  recordSetVar="search" >

</apex:page>
```

[image: This was when style sheet was not added to the vf page]

when style sheet was added to the page

```
<apex:page standardController="case" extensions="UnclaimedTicket" sidebar="false" tabStyle="case"  recordSetVar="search" >

<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.1/css/bootstrap.no-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/> 

  </apex:page>
```

[image: This was when style sheet was added to the page]

by adding the style sheet i am loosing the salesforce and version logos on top right and also the whole page was zoomed in and giving very narrow and closed look.
  Is there any way to over come this ...

Comment: Try to remove unwanted script 1 by 1 which is no longer in use for your code

Comment: @Aryankapoor mean in external style sheet !!

Comment: Means all that script which i gave u in noon na!! from that only remove unwanted script

Comment: @Aryankapoor thanks for that i have removed all the things i have added only the line shown in second piece of code shown above... but i need that link to style sheet badly to achieve my things...

Comment: Now 1 by 1 add that scripts which i provided you and the movement when your  functionality works stop adding scripts

Comment: @Aryankapoor sure will try and let you know...

Comment: Means add 1 script and run your code!! and if that added script leaveraging any functionality than ok if not remove that...and repeat this process

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25138/discussion-between-rajasekhar-and-aryan-kapoor).

Comment: You need to namespace bootstrap so it does not affect DOM elements on the screen outside of the element with the class namespace

Comment: @Eric sure i will check this....

Answer (score 0):

you can try this.

```
<apex:page standardController="case" extensions="UnclaimedTicket" sidebar="false" tabStyle="case"  recordSetVar="search" >
 <apex:stylesheet value="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.1/css/bootstrap.no-icons.min.css" />

 </apex:page>
```

or you can try using a static resource, but if this way works for you while developing, then go for it.
please let me know if this helps.

Comment: thank you... apex:stylesheet  approach haven't worked ,Will try as static resource and let you know...

Comment: opps!!! no luck with static resource too.... might be some problem with css only...

Comment: thanks for that.. i have refered  other css style sheet, even though it didn't worked well but i make it as static resource i was getting those salesforce logos back.. the only thing left is still the page is rendering with slight zoom-in .. i was working on that will let you know when i come out of that.. thanks for the approach

Comment: ok no problem.. Happy to help

Comment: @ajay - Common issue, you must namespace bootstrap to use it with SF and not affect standard Salesforce UI